# What is the reason StandardDeviation doesn't cooperate with Quantity "Percent"?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, units

Consider the following list of numbers

```
y = {13, 0.2, 11.201};
```

Turning `y` into a list of `Quantity`'s and calculating some stats works just as one would expect:

Evaluating

```
Through[{Mean, StandardDeviation}[Quantity[y, "km"]]]
```

returns

> ```
>  {Quantity[8.13367, "Kilometers"], Quantity[6.92939, "Kilometers"]}
> ```

Trying to do the same exact calculations but this time using `"Percent"` as the underlying unit produces the following problem:

```
{8.13367%, 6.92939Sqrt[None]}
```

It seems that `StndardDeviation` is having trouble processing the "%" unit.

One way around this is to define the following auxiliary functions:

```
qf = QuantityUnit /* First;
qsd = (Through[{QuantityMagnitude /* StandardDeviation, qf}[#]] &) /* Apply[Quantity];
```

which essentially assist in deconstructing a `Quantity`, applying `StandardDeviation` and repackaging the result into a `Quantity` with appropriate units.

```
Through[{Mean, qsd}[Quantity[y, "Percent"]]]
```

> ```
> {Quantity[8.13367, "Percent"], Quantity[6.92939, "Percent"]}
> ```

Is this behavior reproducible on different systems than mine?

Can anybody think of a reason why this is happening?

Are there any other ways around this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What version are you on? In V12.1 it seems to work just fine for me (though it returns a unit of `Sqrt[%^2]` rather than just `%`)

Comment: @SjoerdSmit I'm using v.12.0; it's weird it works with some units eg "km" and not with others ie "%";